# Show that $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{GL}_n^+(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Here, $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the standard general linear group and $\operatorname{GL}_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with real entries and positive determinant.

An earlier exercise requires that we show that $\operatorname{GL}_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, so I assume this problem requires the use of the First Isomorphism Theorem. The thing is, though, I just don't understand how to apply it.

My guess is that we can show that $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{GL}_n^+(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ by constructing a homomorphism from $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ whose kernel is $\operatorname{GL}_n^+(\mathbb{R})$, but I'm missing anything with the image.

How would you go about using the FIT to prove this? In addition, and more generally, how does one use the FIT to prove that $G/H \cong J$, where $G, H, J$ are groups.

Comment: use the determinant map after reducing down to showing the sign is all that matters.

Comment: One way of thinking about it: what are the elements of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ that _aren't_ in $GL^+_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I understand, for the most part, the idea of why this is true: negatives and positives "form a group" of order 2, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but how would you apply the FIT to prove this knowing that $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is a normal subgroup?

Comment: The reason I ask is because the example in my book simply states "We use the FIT to show that $\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{T}^1 \cong \mathbb{R}_{>0}$", but doesn't show how this is done.

Comment: Ah! So that's where the image falls out: the surjectivity condition guarantees that the image of the homomorphism is equal to the codomain. Thank you heaps--I think I can do this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: show that $\phi:GL_n(\Bbb R) \to \{-1,1\}$, given by:

$\phi(A) = \dfrac{\det(A)}{|\det(A)|}$

is a surjective group homomorphism, and observe the image is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Just figured this out seconds before you posted this, haha. Thank you for the confirmation! I guess I could have a follow-up question, though. I also used $\{\pm 1\} \cong \mathbb{Z_2}$, but is it possible to construct a mapping directly to $\{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Of course we can construct a mapping directly to $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$.

Let $\varphi: GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{Z_{2}}$; $\varphi(A)=[0]$ if $A\in GL_{n}^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\varphi(A)=[1]$ in other cases. We know that $\det(AB)=\det A\det B$, so it's easy to check that $\varphi(AB)=\varphi(A)+\varphi(B)$, and therfore $\varphi$ is a surjective homomorphism from $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$. The kernel of this homomorphism, of course is $GL_{n}^{+}(\mathbb{R})$.